# Interrupting a thread in Python with a KeyboardException in the main thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a few classes that look more or less like this:

```
import threading
import time

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, interval, callbacks):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.loop)
        self.interval = interval
        self.thread_stop = threading.Event()
        self.callbacks = callbacks

    def loop():
        while not self.thread_stop.is_set():
            #do some stuff...
            for callback in self.callbacks():
                callback()
            time.sleep(self.interval)

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def kill(self):
        self.thread_stop.set()
```

Which I am using from my main thread like this:

```
interval = someinterval
callbacks = [some callbacks]

f = Foo(interval, callbacks)

try:
    f.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    f.kill()
    raise
```

I would like a KeyboardInterrupt to kill the thread after all the callbacks have been completed, but before the loop repeats.  Currently they are ignored and I have to resort to killing the terminal process that the program is running in.

I saw the idea of using threading.Event from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python?rq=1), but it appears like I'm doing it incorrectly, and it's making working on this project a pretty large hassle.

I don't know if it may be relevant, but the callbacks I'm passing access data from the Internet and make heavy use of the retrying decorator to deal with unreliable connections.

---

**EDIT**

After everyone's help, the loop now looks like this inside Foo:

```
    def thread_loop(self):
        while not self.thread_stop.is_set():
            # do some stuff
            # call the callbacks
            self.thread_stop.wait(self.interval)
```

This is *kind of* a solution, although it isn't ideal.  This code runs on [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) and the price of the account is by CPU time.  I'll have to see how much this uses over the course of a day with the constant waking and sleeping of threads, but it at least solves the main issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @shx2 and @jazzpi for putting together the two separate pieces of the puzzle.

so the final code is

```
import threading
import time

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, interval, callbacks):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.loop)
        self.interval = interval
        self.thread_stop = threading.Event()
        self.callbacks = callbacks

    def loop():
        while not self.thread_stop.is_set():
            #do some stuff...
            for callback in self.callbacks():
                callback()
            self.thread_stop.wait(self.interval)

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def kill(self):
        self.thread_stop.set()
```

And then in main

```
interval = someinterval
callbacks = [some, callbacks]
f = Foo(interval, callbacks)
f.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    f.kill()
    raise
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you have a `try-except`-block around `f.start()`, but that returns immediately, so you aren't going to catch `KeyboardInterrupt`s after the thread was started.

You could try adding a while-loop at the bottom of your program like this:

```
f.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    f.kill()
    raise
```

This isn't exactly the most elegant solution, but it should work.

Comment: This *almost* does the trick.  However, it waits until the sleep at the end of the thread loop is over to exit the process.  Putting that same try-except block around the sleep inside the Foo class doesn't work, I think because the KeyboardInterrupt occurs in the main thread.

Comment: Yes, the Exception is thrown in the main thread - you could replace the sleep with a simple `pass`, but that's going to put one of your CPU cores at 100%. There might be a more elegant solution for this, but I think a 0.1 second delay between doing `Ctrl+C` and the program ending is acceptable.

Comment: No, no, the sleep within the loop *inside Foo* has to finish, so in my particular case it's a 10 minute long wait.

Answer (score 1):

@jazzpi's answer correctly addresses the issue you're having in the main thread.

As to the `sleep` in thread's loop, you can simply replace the call to `sleep` with a call to `self.thread_stop.wait(self.interval)`.

This way, your thread wakes up as soon as the stop event is set, or after waiting (i.e. sleeping) for `self.interval` seconds. ([Event docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects))